# delphi send message before application.run

Tags: delphi

I am developing an application to prevent of multiple instance. I try to send message to first app instance using wm_copydata and it dosn't work, but I can send message via WM_SYSCOMMAND

```
if not checkInstance.RestoreIfRunning(Application.Handle,oldHandle, 1) then
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(Tfrm_main, frm_main);
  Application.Run;
end
else
begin

stringToSend := 'My Message';

aCopyData.dwData := 0; //use it to identify the message contents
aCopyData.cbData := 1 + Length(stringToSend) ;
aCopyData.lpData := PChar(stringToSend) ;

SendMessage(oldHandle,WM_COPYDATA,longint(oldHandle),longint(@aCopyData));
end;

....

mainform:

private
procedure WMCopyData(var Msg: TWMCopyData); message WM_COPYDATA;
.
.
.
procedure mainForm.WMCopyData(var Msg: TWMCopyData);
begin
ShowMessage('received!');
end;
```

Comment: Check if the `oldHandle` contains a valid handle to your `mainForm` window. Also, you can (should) return `True` to the `Msg.Result` property on the receiver side and check the returned value of the `SendMessage` on the sender side. Besides, parameter types of the `SendMessage` function are `WParam` and `LParam`, not `longint` as was written in some utter code snippets over the Internet.

Comment: oldhandle is valid handle. also, I have put return value for Msg.Result but not working. I have used this parameter type and it working

Comment: FWIW, your casts are wrong. Cast to `WPARAM` and `LPARAM`. That way your code can work in 64 bit.

Comment: I have changed sendMessage but not working again:  `SendMessage(oldHandle, WM_COPYDATA, WPARAM(oldHandle), LPARAM(@aCopyData)) ;`

Comment: Well, so the `oldHandle` did not contain a valid handle to your `mainForm` window as I asked you to check.

Comment: Yes, You are true. When I was working with Delphi2005 this code works fine and this make me sure it's correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are sending the message to the wrong window. Or another way of viewing it, your are attempting to handle the message in the wrong window.

You have:

```
if not checkInstance.RestoreIfRunning(Application.Handle, oldHandle, 1) then
```

Of course, we cannot see the code behind `checkInstance.RestoreIfRunning`, but my spider sense tells me that the handle returned in `oldHandle` is the application handle rather than the main window handle. What leads me to this suspicion is that:

1. You pass `Application.Handle` to `RestoreIfRunning` and so presumably that is the handle the is seen when the second application attempts to run.
2. You succeed in getting `WM_SYSCOMMAND` to respond, presumably to restore the first instance of the application, but that is a message that is handled by the application window procedure.

So, handle the message in the application window procedure rather than the main form window procedure, and all should be well. Use `Application.HookMainWindow` to achieve that.

Comment: oldHandle and application.handle are different. Also, oldHandle is application.handle (not form handle).

Comment: *Also, oldHandle is application.handle (not form handle).* That is exactly what I hypothesise above. The solution is exactly as I describe. The message is delivered to the application and not the form. So you need to handle it in the application window procedure.

Comment: Thanks @David I just put one line of code there to find form handle: `oldHandle := FindWindow('mainForm', nil);`
everything working fine!

Comment: @poostchi Well, I would not do it that way. What if another app has the same name for their main form. You should use `HookMainWindow`.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution

**Unit1.pas**

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    procedure WMApp(var msg: TMessage); message WM_APP;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.WMApp(var msg: TMessage);
begin
  Application.Restore;
end;

end.
```

Execute: **Project - View Source**

Project1.dpr

```
program Project1;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  Windows,
  Messages,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}
var
  Hwnd: THandle;

begin
  Hwnd := FindWindow('TForm1', nil);

  if Hwnd = 0 then
  begin
    Application.Initialize;
    Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
    Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
    Application.Run;
  end else
  begin
    if not IsWindowVisible(Hwnd) then
      PostMessage(Hwnd, WM_APP, 0, 0);
    SetForegroundWindow(Hwnd);
  end;
end.
```

That's all

Comment: I think the asker is trying to make their solution (mutex based) work rather than use your different, somewhat more flimsy solution. Your solution is not robust.